# What is the origin of "6 to 8 weeks" and is it really the Crazy Frog?

Tags: discussion, fun, memes

Last week I was watching a TV show. During a dialog, one character asked the other something like "So how long will it take you to do it" and the answer was simply "6 to 8 weeks".

This led me to believe Jeff was just using a known meme and just applying it here, [over five years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/152859), but all my searches utterly failed and pointed on this very meta post as the origin of the meme.

1. [Searching just for 6 to 8 weeks](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&q=6+to+8+weeks) without quotes or anything:

   > [image]

   First out of nearly two billion results. Nice.
2. [Searching for "6 to 8 weeks"](http://www.google.co.uk/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=%226+to+8+weeks%22) with quotes, same just with less total results:

   > [image]

   Then I found <del>this post</del> (Link removed: [site closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HitQuarters), now a [phishing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing) site), an interview with *[Erik Wernquist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Frog)* who is the creator of [Crazy Frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Frog):

   > How much time did it take in the beginning to program it?

   > The first animation I did at my spare time. I worked about **6 to 8 weeks** on building the character and making the first animation

Is it coincidence, fate or something that Jeff read and later used himself? :)

Comment: It originated with JeffAtwood, during the development of Stack Overflow. Beta was said to be 6 to 8 weeks out; needless to say he missed that target.

Comment: @Martijn might be! Anyway found a bug in markup, can't format the quote properly. Will investigate further later. :)

Comment: @Sha: repro & fix for the formatting misbehavior: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181300/158667 - not sure what part of that is a bug. I'd say the way you formatted the image quotes isn't kosher, and I'm surprised that part works.

Comment: as far as I can tell, this dates back to at least 1989, Muppet babies [episode 603: Six-to-Eight Weeks](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_603:_Six-to-Eight_Weeks) "The Babies anxiously await the arrival of a playhouse that Nanny ordered for them, which was _supposed to arrive in six to eight weeks_..."

Comment: @gnat valid candidate for an answer! :-)

Comment: @Mat thanks, so the bug was the image was part of the list where it shouldn't be! :/

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd [there you go](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190745/165773) :)

Comment: No. The first one (1, _86_ 0, 000) is definently a conspiracy theory.

Comment: @Cole yep that's possible!

Comment: Should this question be merged into the Many memes of meta?

Comment: It is also found in Phineas and Ferb show [6-8 weeks in Phineas and Ferb?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/85117/48608). It is possible that the show took it from Jeff's words.

Comment: Someone check if Barnier used the expression even before Atwood ;) https://uk.reuters.com/article/uk-britain-eu-barnier/eus-barnier-says-brexit-deal-with-britain-realistic-in-6-8-weeks-idUKKCN1LQ1O7 A search finds https://www.utwente.nl/en/bms/pa/research/wessel/wessel3.pdf 1999 - note drawn up by Barnier in his function as chairman of the European ...... the Member States of the Council of Europe during the year in periods of 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @Nemo nice find!

Comment: [_The Simpsons_ episode _The Canine Mutiny_](http://www.simpsonsarchive.com/episodes/4F16.txt) referred to the "6 to 8 weeks" concept in 1997 when Bart received his fraudulent credit card "6 to 8 weeks" after filling it out.

Comment: [_The Simpsons_ episode _Marge in Chains_](https://www.simpsonsarchive.com/episodes/9F20.html) referred to the "6 to 8 weeks" concept in 1993 when the flu-contaminated "Juice Loosener" took "6 to 8 weeks" to arrive in Springfield from Osaka.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Searching web for *six to eight weeks* leads to [Muppet Babies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muppet_Babies) TV series, Episode 603: [Six-to-Eight Weeks](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Episode_603:_Six-to-Eight_Weeks) which sounds painfully familiar:

> The Babies anxiously await the arrival of a playhouse that [Nanny](http://muppet.wikia.com/wiki/Nanny) ordered for them, which was supposed to arrive in six to eight weeks...
>
> [image: http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070205200441/muppet/images/5/52/MBTitle--6-to-8-Weeks.jpg]

Muppet babies wiki says "Air Date September 30, 1989", about 20 years before Stack Overflow and several years before [Crazy Frog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crazy_Frog). :)

Comment: Until better (or official from Jeff Himself) answer will arrive, accepting this as the truth. :)

Answer (score 38):

I can't prove that this is what Jeff had in mind, but [cereal box mail-order prizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cereal_box_prize)* like [secret decoder rings](http://home.comcast.net/~jrolsen2/premiums/ovaltine.html) or [propeller beanies](http://www.gocomics.com/printable/calvinandhobbes/2010/04/16/) famously ask you to "please allow" "4-6 weeks", or "6-8 weeks" for delivery after sending away for them.

I've found two mentions of that specific time frame:

http://www.x-entertainment.com/articles/0695/

> ...and Pac-Man vowed to never again make kids wait 6-8 weeks for four pieces of colored hard plastic.

http://thriftstorecowboyvintage.com/fun-stuff/a-brief-history-of-capn-crunch-cereal-toy-giveaways

> Is it just me, or has the wait for mail in offers increased from 6-8 weeks to 10-12?

Far from conclusive, and I certainly don't want to take credit away from Jeff for promoting the meme, but these things have been around since the early part of the 20th century, and they're definitely an element of American culture. It's what I always think of when I hear this phrase (and I'd wager that it's where the Muppet Babies title came from, too, given the plot).

---

*Technically a "premium", apparently, if it isn't in the box to begin with.

Comment: +1 for excellent research, but only Jeff can know for sure. :)