# Is a birthday a review audits free day?

Tags: support, profile-page, review-audits

Normally I have several review audits each day. But today I haven't seen one yet.

Is this linked to the birthday date in my profile or is it pure chance?

Comment: Happy birthday!!

Comment: Shouldn't this be tagged `fun`?

Comment: [Happy birthday!^^](http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/aoz942X_460sa.gif)

Comment: [Congratulations](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=us3dQ0nnlHY)

Comment: Pragmatically, I doubt it. But it will exist if we believe in it.

Comment: Happy birthday. Here's 5 reputation points.

Comment: Or maybe they're just silent, to be assessed when your birthday ends, to avoid giving you the bad news on a happy day.

Comment: Maybe the audits are planning a suprise party and will all show up at once? =o

Comment: The earth has run around the sun approximately an integer number of times since you were born. Enjoy your special day.

Comment: May be devs gift you to be [a robo](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=robo+approvers) on your birthday.

Comment: Hey it's my birthday too! Stop stealing dates!

Comment: It's a coincidence, there's a random chance per-review that you might get an audit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You posted this just to get happy birthday comments, didn't you? :P

Anyway, there is a 99.99% chance that this is pure coincidence and you can get audits today just like you have the chance of not getting any audits on another day.

Comment: But there's still a 0.01% chance, right? Anyway, your birthday is only 0.274% of the year, so isn't that quite likely?

Answer (score 19):

My hypothesis is that according to [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/151167/toon-krijthe) you are 46 years of age so maybe you're approaching that point of life where you did indeed get audits but then they just "slipped your memory"? Be assured this is not ageism and I in [6 to 8 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190736/what-is-the-origin-of-6-to-8-weeks-and-is-it-really-the-crazy-frog) I expect to be the same. Meanwhile enjoy:

[image]